# Apache Spark Latency Causes

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some code that we initially implemented in SAS. I was rewriting/porting it to different technologies with the aim of cutting costs and seeking "better performance". My first impl was in Python (Pandas + NumPy), and performance was much better than SAS, however I was only limited to 1 CPU core for most of the work.

I rewrote the code in PySpark and Scala, and performance is sightly worse. I've noticed that there are some large pauses in the Spark code. Please refer to the screenshot below.

[image: Spark Event Timeline]

When Spark is 'pausing' during this processing, I've observed no disk/CPU activity. This is all in a single-machine, so it can't be network shuffles.

Does anyone know what the cause could be, and how to generally reduce this latency?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a standalone spark setup. You can dig dipper in  spark jobs, stages to validate is it a spark method/code problem, GC problem or anything else as you suspect.
It might happen that one executor is doing the heavy processing which is taking time. note: As executor is limited by core usage, you might see less cpu utilization overall but tasks execution is slow because of lack of parallelism. Single machine can degrade performance because of many hard to troubleshoot problems (resource sharing is very difficult to troubleshoot, context switching etc.)

Comment: There are many possible causes. One suggestion would be to inspect your executors when you notice these "Pauses". You can see what exactly is running on executors if you look at their thread dumps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll look into what's running on executors, although I haven't seen anything so far. I've noticed the same behaviour in both a Linux (still stand-alone) server as well as on my desktop. On the linux setup, it's only Spark that's running, so there shouldn't be interference or resource contention.

My corporate overlords are looking for "real-time" performance, but these "pauses" are killing us.